macOS: Disable popup showing accented characters when holding down a key - App specific
This is a variant on this question: macOS: Disable popup showing accented characters when holding down a key
I want to disable the accent popup when holding down a key, but only for certain applications.
defaults write -g ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false will disable it for all applications. However, I want to only disable it for certain applications. I want key repeating in "coding" related applications (ex. VS-Code) but accented characters in "writing" related applications (ex. MS Word).
By default Terminal is setup to have key repeating instead of accented characters when it is setup system wide setup as accented chars. I basically want to extend this to also be true in VS-Code.
